# How to position an object with a class to be shown in a division?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a download button to be shown in a specified div I have. But I don't know the exact CSS to do this. I want to make a button shown in a specified div only if there is a link with a pre specified class anywhere in that page.

Please  help me with HTML and CSS codes..  I don't want PHP codes please...

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: any code would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with the Id selector as compare to class selector if you want to add it in specific div.

suppose you have div
`<div id="mydiv"></div>`
and you have button like
`var button=<button ... />`
so you can add in jquery like
`$("#mydiv").append(button);`
you can also use prepend and html method as per your requirement.

Comment: I think it will work. But I don't know CSs to make it positioned in a specified division. Please explain the code you have written and help with a little css if you can...

Comment: you can create one css class as per w3school or bootstrap website for your button and div and add them with class="your class" in <button> or <div> and specify position related aspects in your css class.